# Show and Hide Layout

Tags: java, android, animation, layout

Good morning, guys I have the following problem I have a linear layout that is hidden it will work as an icon bar when clicking on a button it slides and is visible when clicking on another button it slides and goes back to being hidden I also added a function so that after 10 seconds the layout is hidden again on its own but I have a problem because if the layout receives a precise click this time resets the count ie after having no more click event the layout performs the function of counting the ten seconds and be hidden, how can I do this? follow my code snippet with the function

```
final LinearLayout barraBrilho = view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout3);

    barraBrilho.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    brilho.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onClick(View view) {
                                      if (!gone) {

                                          Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.translate_layout_right);
                                          barraBrilho.startAnimation(anim);
                                          barraBrilho.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                          gone = true;
                                      } else {
                                          barraBrilho.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                          Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.translate_layout_left);
                                          barraBrilho.startAnimation(anim);
                                          gone = false;


                                          new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void run() {
                                                  if (!gone) {
                                                      Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.translate_layout_right);
                                                      barraBrilho.startAnimation(anim);
                                                      barraBrilho.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                      gone = true;
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }, 10000);
                                      }
                                  }
                              });
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you want to achieve ? it's not clear at all.

Comment: Maybe with a flag parameter in your class , you could check the state of openning or closing and according it you do some tasks. Also you could when clicking check visiblity of your object , if the object is visible ,you must active your timer(starting).If the object is close , do not any tasks.

Comment: @Walid what I want is that after the layout is displayed, trigger a 10 second timer and if there is no touch event on the screen the layout disappears again but if I touch the screen the timer resets and counts until it has not no more touch and time passes, is it clearer?

Comment: then, you can check the visibility when performing the touch, like @maniaq said.

Comment: so, but if it is visible and I execute the touch, I wish the timer reset is just what I am unable to do, 
I don't know if it was very clear but the idea is not after clicking on the button it counts ten seconds and closing, the idea is that the timer is independent of the button to close if I click the button to close it will be instantaneous but if I don't click it waits the timer to close